# How to implement scroll & card-stack like animation in React / TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-animations, tailwind-css

I want to implement scrolling animations like below in React & Nextjs (and I am using TailwindCSS)

Not sure how to explain this effect (scroll -> stack -> appear), but the user scroll down, and the next part shows up in a fixed place. Then, once it scrolls to a certain point, it starts moving.

I assume it is a combination of the `z-index` but not sure how to implement it.

[image: Example]

Here is the above site I found and want to know how to achieve this kind of scrolling effect.

https://www.abstract.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is done with the help of `position: sticky;` at block two `class="s-heading-first"`.

```css
.section.s-heading-first {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0%;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 27rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

I think that can help you.

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  display: block;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;

  font-family: "Gt america standard", sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}

.section.s-hero {
  z-index: 10;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 0rem;
  padding-top: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: 7.5rem;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 10px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 10px);
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.section.s-radius {
  padding-top: 0rem;
  padding-bottom: 15rem;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5rem;
}

.section.s-radius.sr-large {
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

.section.s-heading {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 22.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.section.s-heading-first {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 27rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-grid {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.heading-xl {
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 0.95;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
}

.col-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -1rem;
  margin-bottom: -2rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-12-d {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.section-radius {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5rem;
  background-color: #000;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.background-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.background-blurple {
  background-color: #dadbf1;
}

.container-max {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.heading-lines {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
}

.heading-line {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0.7rem;
  height: 4.9rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b3b8ee;
}

.heading-line.hl-first {
  border-top: 2px solid #b3b8ee;
}

.z-9 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 9px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 9px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.z-7 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 7;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 7px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 7px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.section-head-bg-extension {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: -5rem;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
}

.c-body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .container-max {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  .section {
    padding-right: 5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .heading-xl {
    font-size: 6.5rem;
    line-height: 0.98;
  }

  .heading-line {
    bottom: 0.8rem;
    height: 6.9rem;
  }

  .c-body {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .section.s-hero {
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 2.5rem;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
  }

  .section.s-heading {
    padding-top: 30vh;
  }

  .section.s-heading-first {
    padding-top: 30vh;
  }

  .heading-xl {
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 1;
  }

  .container-max {
    max-width: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .section {
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }

  .section.s-hero {
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }

  .section.s-hero.s-hero-versions {
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
  }

  .section.s-radius {
    padding-bottom: 7.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2.5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2.5rem;
  }

  .section.s-heading {
    padding-top: 7.5rem;
  }

  .section.s-heading-first {
    padding-top: 15vh;
  }

  .heading-xl {
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .hide-mobile-wide {
    display: none;
  }

  .section-radius {
    height: 2.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2.5rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2.5rem;
  }

  .z-9 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 9px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 9px);
  }

  .z-7 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 7px);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 7px);
  }

  .section-head-bg-extension {
    top: -2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .section {
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
  }

  .section.s-hero {
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
  }

  .heading-xl {
    font-size: 2.75rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="c-body">
  <div class="page">
    <div id="content" class="main">
      <section class="section s-hero s-hero-versions">
        <div class="section-radius"></div>
        <div class="container-max">
          container-max
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class="section s-heading-first background-blurple z-9"> 
        <div class="container-max">
          <div class="flex-grid">
            <div class="col-wrapper">
              <div class="col col-12-d">
                <div class="heading-lines hide-mobile-wide">
                  <div class="heading-line hl-first"></div>
                  <div class="heading-line"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-grid">
                  Template
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <section class="section s-radius sr-large background-blurple z-9">
        <div class="container-max">
          <div class="flex-grid">
            <p>
              Template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template,
              template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template, template
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="section s-heading background-white z-7">
        <div class="section-head-bg-extension background-white"></div>
        <div class="container-max">
          <h2 class="heading-xl text-center">Template text-center</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```